# How to add subquery in views to remove particular type of rows?

Tags: 7, views

I have applied join to **users** table with **node_revision** table like below:

```
function custom_overrides_views_data_alter(&$data) {

  $data['users']['node_revision'] = array(
    'title' => t('Users revisions authored'),
    'help' => t('Relate a user to their revisions'),
    'relationship' => array(
      'base' => 'node_revision',
      'base field' => 'uid',
      'relationship field' => 'uid',
      'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
      'label' => t('revisions bubbla'),
    ),
  );
}
```

And by creating view now I got number of revisions per user like below:

> Westerberg (15752)
>
> Eriksson (4305)
>
> Jakob (4182)
>
> Andersson (4153)

But now I want to remove those revisions which are created when user created node first time ie: will only show edits but not the revisions which are created first time when new node was created. To solve this logic is to remove nodes having below true:

**excluding the “first time created” nodes (original node revision)**

```
node.created = node_revision.timestamp
```

I tried using query alter but it uses quotes around field please suggest how to remove that ?

```
if ($view->name == "my_view") {

    $sub_query = db_select('node', 'n')
      ->fields('n', array('created'))
      ->condition('n.created', 'node_revision_users.timestamp');


    $view->query->where[1]['conditions'][] = array(
      'field' => 'node_revision_users.timestamp',
      'value' => $sub_query,
      'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    );

  }
```

**Output problem is like screenshot:**

[image]

Please suggest! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `where()` to match table columns instead of condition

```
if ($view->name == "my_view") {
    $sub_query = db_select('node', 'n')
      ->fields('n', array('created'))
      ->where("n.created = node_revision_users.timestamp");

      $view->query->where[1]['conditions'][] = array(
        'field' => 'node_revision_users.timestamp',
        'value' => $sub_query,
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
      );
}
```

**Update**

Why where() not condition()

**Syntax for condition:**

```
$query->condition($field, $value = NULL, $operator = '=')
```

shows condition() is for building standard condition fragement

**Syntax for where:**

```
$query->where($snippet, $args = array())
```

shows where() is for building any arbitrary SQL as conditional fragment.

`$snippet` may contain any legal SQL fragment.